# JSF 2.2 File Upload Not Working (action never called)

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to get a really simple example I found online to work, I've tried searching everywhere but can't seem to find a solution.

This is the bean that I'm using:

```
@Named("uploadBean")
@RequestScoped
public class UploadBean {
    private Part file;
    private String fileContent;

    public void upload() {
        try {
            fileContent = new Scanner(file.getInputStream())
                    .useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error handling
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Uploaded!"));
    }

    public Part getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(Part file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getFileContent() {
        return fileContent;
    }

    public void setFileContent(String fileContent) {
        this.fileContent = fileContent;
    }
}
```

This is the form that uses it:

```
<h:form id="file-upload-test" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputFile id="in-file" value="#{uploadBean.file}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Upload!" action="#{uploadBean.upload}"/>
</h:form>
```

Whenever I try to upload a file, upload() is never called.

Maybe the answer is too obvious, but I'm using JSF 2.2.7 and I'm not sure why this simple example shouldn't work?

Comment: Which server? Does it support CDI? Which faces-config.xml version have you declared? Which web.xml version have you declared? What if you use a regular non-upload form? How does the HTTP request payload look like? Have you tried latest Mojarra version (currently 2.2.12)?

Comment: I'm using Glassfish 4. Faces-config.xml is version 2.2, and web.xml is version 3.1. A regular form works fine and calls the same method properly. The HTTP request payload shows the file in the request. I updated the Glassfish JSF to 2.2.12 form 2.2.7 (and verified pragmatically), but still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Do you have any filters in the web application which might consume the request body (e.g. via `request.getParameter()`) before it hits the `FacesServlet`?

Comment: That was it. I completely forgot that I had PrettyFaces filtering the page. Thanks so much for your help!